# Oocyte cryopreservation: genes from three parents?

Tags: genetics, reproduction, pregnancy

Recently, I've heard of something called [Oocyte cryopreservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oocyte_cryopreservation), where a (fertilized, I think) egg from a woman is extracted, frozen and later thawed and reinserted into the woman to delay pregnancy.

Now, this is just an idea, I don't know if this is actually possible, but can this frozen egg be implanted into a *different* woman, who isn't the original owner of the egg? If yes, whose genes would the child inherit? Would it get genes from all three parents, or just from the original owner of the sperm and egg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: yes it is possible to donate an oocyte to another woman. This is typically done in assisted reproduction and combined with in vitro fertilization. The child would only inherit the genes from the donor oocyte and the sperm, as the genetic material is enclosed in the oocyte and sperm. There is no genetic contribution of the recipient.

You can find more information on the corresponding wikipedia page: 
[Egg donation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_donation)